# Android can I write layout xml file programmatically and load it with setContentView(R.layout.test_1) function?

Tags: android, xml, layout, storage

I want to write programmatically xml layout file to SD card or other storage and when the app load it will load the file as layout with setContentView function or any other way. is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible since the layout files are actually compiled XML files, means you cannot change, add or remove them at run time. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is doing a Custom XML Decoder that reads your XML from file, then create programatically the Views you need, and then setContentView(View).  The Decoder isn't trivial if you use many parameters in the XML.

Comment: Ya agree with this approach. And if you don't need to load a complex layout, consider simplify the XML schema so you don't have to write complex decoder.

Comment: Hi,if i will get the xml String decoded from WebSrevice,can it help me to skip the xml Decoder solution?what it mean "create programatically the Views you need" ? do you mean i need to parse the xml and build one by one elments and properties? or there is a way to create view programmaticlly and load the xml to it by simple command (like view.load(xml_doc or xml_string))?Thank you.

Comment: you need to create one by one all the views parsing the properties. You cannot create a view from a string that represents the XML remote file.

you need a Reference in R file to create a View (inflating) or create it manually, programming

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use method inflate(XmlPullParser parser....) of LayoutInflater.
But resources will be loaded from resources of a context.